# How to center graphs in a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have the following figure:

[image]

and I´d like to have the two graphs of the third line centered. I´ve trying to get it using packages like `cowplot`and *grid_arrange* from `ggplot2` but with no success because they change their width to fit with the width of the other two rows (like in this example),

[image]

Is it possible to have the last two graphs centered without changing their width?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant code, but it works. AFAIK there is a package where you can specify for each plot the size and location, but I haven't found it. I only used `cowplot` and function `plot_grid`

Generating plot

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x * 2 + rnorm(100)
plt.df <- data.frame(x, y)

p     <- ggplot(plt.df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Arranging them in grids

```
cowplot::plot_grid(
  cowplot::plot_grid(p, p, p, p, p, p, ncol = 3, nrow = 2),
  cowplot::plot_grid(NULL, p, p, NULL, rel_widths = c(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5), nrow = 1),
  nrow = 2,
  rel_heights = c(2, 1)
)
```

[image]

I first define a grid of 6 plots as usual. I then define a grid of 4 plots, two of them are null, and use the `rel_widths` parameter to determine their size.
To combine all of them I again invoke `plot_grid`, which accepts the two previous grids. Now define the `rel_heights` parameter to make sure they are all similar in size (since there are two grids, one with twice more plots than the other, then the ratio should be 2).

Comment: thanks for your useful explanation. I overlooked `cowplot::plot_grid` perhaps because the package is a add-on to ggplot and my GAM plots are done with `plot`. But after your hint, I´ve seen that it´s posibble to arrange plots not generated with ggplot. I hope to get it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in base R by specifying an appropriate matrix for `layout`.

```r
layout.m <- matrix(c(rep(1:6, each=2), 
                     0, rep(7:8, each=2), 0), 
                   nrow=3, byrow=T)
```

This matrix specifies the locations of eight figures in a 3 × 6 grid layout with two cells left empty.

```r
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    2    2    3    3
# [2,]    4    4    5    5    6    6
# [3,]    0    7    7    8    8    0
```

Now just set the layout and do the plotting.

```r
layout(layout.m)
par(mar=c(4, 4.5, 1, .5))
x <- 1:100
for (i in 1:8) {
  y <- rnorm(100)
  plot(x, y)
}
```

[image: Final layout]